# The more complex CNN model seems to face with the underfitting during training

Tags: regression, neural-networks

I have confused about this problem for a long time. I am using CNN model to do a regression problem. When I use some simple model with fewer parameters, the training loss would decrease. But When I use some more complex model, the training loss will remain at a higher value and not change. I think the model should face with underfitting, but I think the more complex model should be more powerful to learn from data and the training loss should be lower, the figure below is my simple model architecture and its loss curve:

[image]
[image]

Then the images below is the architecture for a more complex model and its loss curve:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Could be the vanishing gradient problem, or a poor optimizer configuration.

Comment: Do u mean it may be trapped in a local minimum or saddle point?

Comment: I use adam(lr=1e-3, decay=1e-3 / 200) as my optimizer, I think it can escape from local minimum or saddle point

Comment: How do you know that learning rate is the right size? How do you know that the weight decay is not too large?

Comment: as an aside your "complex model" also has fewer layers... i recommend to always change only one thing at a time

Comment: thank you for your comment. The thing is If I also use three Convolution layers (same as the complex model), and each layer with fewer filters, the training loss can still decrease. Or if I increase filters in each convolutional layer, the training loss can also decrease. Seems that the 'overfitting' only happens for some specific architecture.